# Double commutant theorem when $C^*$-subalgebra does not contain identity operator $1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Double commutant theorem:** For a unital $C^*$-subalgebra $M \subset B(H)$, one has
$$\smash{\overline M}^\text{SOT}=\smash{\overline M}^\text{WOT}=M''.$$

**My question:**
For a  $C^*$-subalgebra $M \subset B(H)$ but don't assume $M$ contains identity operator  $1$, does
$$\smash{\overline M}^\text{SOT}=\smash{\overline M}^\text{WOT}=M''?$$

Comment: $M''$ is unchanged upon adjoining $1$, so it equals the strong and weak operator closures of $\mathbb C + M$.  By the way, in terms of TeX, don't use $M^{''}$ `$M^{''}$`; instead use $M''$ `$M''$` or $M^{\prime\prime}$ `$M^{\prime\prime}$`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: LSpice, thanks your edit

Comment: As @LSpice points out, $M''$ always contains the identity operator $I\in B(H)$. Now think about whether every ${\rm C}^*$-subalgebra of $M_2({\bf C})$ contains the identity matrix $I_2$ ...

Comment: If $K$ is the essential space for $M$, namely $K=\overline{\text{span}}\{T(\xi): T\in M, \xi\in H\}$,
then $H=K\oplus K^\perp$ and $M$ acts on $H$ like $M\oplus0$, while 
$$M''=\smash{\overline M}^{\text{SOT}}\oplus \mathbb{C}I_{K^\perp}.$$